# error object reference not set to an instance of an object in vb

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlclient

i have a problem. when i running the project and after i click "SAVE" button, this error message will display https://www.dropbox.com/s/drpopoqi3etob3d/Presentation1.png

below is the code of the project

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
```

Public Class frmAddNewStaffAdmin

```
Dim con As SqlClient.SqlConnection
Dim dbSource As String
Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        If Len(Trim(cboRole.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select user type", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            cboRole.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtStaffID.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Staff ID", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtStaffID.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtStaffName.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Staff Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtStaffName.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtUsername.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Username", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtUsername.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtPassword.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtPassword.Focus()
            Return

        End If

        dbSource = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

        con = New SqlConnection(dbSource)

        con.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [User] ([Staff_ID], [Staff_Role], [Staff_Name], [Username], [Password]) VALUES (@StaffID, @Role, @StaffName, @Username, @Password) "

        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_ID", txtStaffID.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", cboRole.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffName", txtStaffName.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)

        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql)


        MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        con.Close()



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

End Sub

Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click

    Me.Hide()
    frmStaffAdmin.Show()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What line is the exception thrown on?  What reference on that line is `Nothing`?   It's most likely going to be something before a dot, although not guaranteed to be.

Comment: i do the break point. and the error start at line cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correctly ordered. You use the SqlCommand before its initialization and of course this results in the mentioned error

```
    dbSource = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

    con = New SqlConnection(dbSource)

    con.Open()

    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [User] ([Staff_ID], [Staff_Role], [Staff_Name], [Username], [Password]) VALUES (@StaffID, @Role, @StaffName, @Username, @Password) "

    cmd = New SqlCommand(sql)

    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffID", txtStaffID.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", cboRole.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffName", txtStaffName.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    con.Close()
```

Moved the initialization of the SqlCommand before its first usage and moved the ExecuteNonQuery as the last instruction

Comment: after i change the ordered. i get this error "must declare the scalar variable at "@StaffID"

Comment: The parameter placeholder is `@StaffID`, the parameter name is `@Staff_ID`, they must be identical. Answer updated

Comment: the data is successful save but in the data not insert in database. why? tq answering my question

Comment: How do you look if the data has been inserted or not? Are you using Server Explorer window inside Visual Studio?

Comment: yes. i use server-based database inside the visual studio.i look the data from the data connection > HMS.mdf > table > user > right click > show table data

Comment: If you are writing a Winform application, the |DataDirectory| substitution string used in your connection string refers to the working directory of your running project. Inside VS this directory is BIN\DEBUG (or x86) version. So the data is inserted in the database present in that directory. Your Server Explorer probably has a connection string that points to a database in the project folder. That's the reason you don't see your changes with Server Explorer. Try to add another connection pointing to the database in BIN\DEBUG folder

Comment: sorry wrong question.actually, how to add another connection pointing to the database in BIN/DEBUG? sorry again. i'm a beginner

Comment: Go To Server Explorer from the View Menu, right click on Connections and select Add Connection, for Server Name select or type `.\SQLEXPRESS` and Attach a Database file browsing to your BIN\DEBUG folder. After confirm, you could Rename the connection again with a right click. Give it a meaningful name to distinguish from the other connections